# No controls found in PlaceHolder when adding programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a weird issue which I'm not so sure on how to resolve. What I'm trying to do is get the values from some controls when clicking a button. The controls are in a Web User Control so I load the control as many times I need (each control value is returned by public properties I have assigned). They are then added to a PlaceHolder. So I first add the controls by clicking a button:

```
    protected void AddControls
    {
        MyMyWebUserControl CustInfo = (MyWebUserControl)LoadControl("MyWebUserControl.ascx");

        for (int c = 0; c <= 10; c++)
        {
             CustInfo.ID = "CustomCtrl" + c + 1;
             myPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(CustInfo);
        }
    }
```

I enter some info into the controls displayed and use a second button to get the values and save the info

```
    protected void btnGetValueFromControls_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         foreach (MyWebUserControl ctrl in myPlaceHolder.Controls)
               {
                  myObj.Name = ctrl.Name;
                  myObj.Surname = ctrl.Surname;
               }
          SaveCustomer
     }
```

The count in myPlaceHolder is always 0.

I have tried adding some code to test postback at page load

```
if(!(Page.IsPostBack))
{
   AddControls();
}
```

Which doesn't resolve.

Comment: You say "i first add the controls by clicking a button". This makes me think you are trying to add the controls during a postback. Is that true? That would cause the `!(Page.IsPostBack)` to prevent AddControls from getting called.

Comment: The user has the option to enter the number of controls they require (E.g. If they wanted to add additional drivers to their policy). Once they enter how many additional drivers they like to add they press a button which displays that many lines of the control. Hope that made sense?

Comment: Makes sense - you call AddControls() when the first button is pressed and they show up, but it is after the second button is pressed that the collection comes back as empty? I think this might be your problem: http://forums.asp.net/t/1186195.aspx?FAQ+Why+do+dynamic+controls+disappear+on+postback+and+not+raise+events+ (at least the disappear part)

Comment: Not sure if ive missed something but both button 1 and 2 are in the markup. The placeHolder only holds the textbox which allows the user to enter details. The link seems to be looking at a dynamically created button which i dont??

Comment: I see why that isn't completely clear. In your case, it is the all of the `MyMyWebUserControl` that are behaving like the "button2" from the article.

Comment: You might also consider using an asp:repeater to generate the list of controls too - it should be happy through the postbacks.